# How to combine triggers

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, triggers

SQL newbie looking for help.

I'm using SQL Server 2008.

At the moment I have 2 triggers, which both relate to the same table.

Is is possible to combine these 2 triggers or is it better practice to keep them separate?

```
ALTER TRIGGER PingtreeNode2_IU_Trig
ON dbo.PingtreeNode
FOR INSERT, UPDATE
AS
IF NOT EXISTS (
                SELECT
                        pt.ID
                    FROM
                        PingtreeTier pt
                    INNER JOIN
                        inserted i ON
                            pt.ID = i.PingtreeTierID
                    INNER JOIN
                        Product p ON
                            i.ProductID = p.ID
                    WHERE
                        pt.ProductServiceTypeID = p.ServiceTypeID
                )
BEGIN
    ROLLBACK TRANSACTION
END

ALTER TRIGGER PingtreeNode_IU_Trig
ON dbo.PingtreeNode
FOR INSERT, UPDATE
AS
IF NOT EXISTS (
                SELECT
                        pt.ID
                    FROM
                        Pingtree pt
                    INNER JOIN
                        PingtreeTier pt2 ON
                            pt.ID = pt2.PingtreeID
                    INNER JOIN
                        inserted i ON
                            pt2.ID = i.PingtreeTierID
                    INNER JOIN
                        Product p ON
                            i.ProductID = p.ID
                    WHERE
                        pt.ProductTypeID = p.TypeID
                )
BEGIN
    ROLLBACK TRANSACTION
END
```

Comment: Why arent you using [FOREIGN KEYS](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175464(v=sql.105).aspx) for this, rather than rolling your own validation?

Comment: This way means that we don't have unecessary keys in in my normalised database

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
ALTER TRIGGER PingtreeNode2_IU_Trig_Combined
ON dbo.PingtreeNode
FOR INSERT, UPDATE
AS
BEGIN
  SET NOCOUNT ON;
IF(   
   (
   NOT EXISTS (
               SELECT pt.ID
               FROM PingtreeTier pt INNER JOIN inserted i 
               ON   pt.ID = i.PingtreeTierID
               INNER JOIN Product p 
               ON i.ProductID = p.ID
               WHERE pt.ProductServiceTypeID = p.ServiceTypeID 
               ) 
    )          
   OR 
    (
   NOT EXISTS (
                SELECT pt.ID
                FROM Pingtree pt INNER JOIN PingtreeTier pt2 
                ON pt.ID = pt2.PingtreeID
                INNER JOIN inserted i 
                ON  pt2.ID = i.PingtreeTierID
                INNER JOIN Product p 
                ON i.ProductID = p.ID
                WHERE  pt.ProductTypeID = p.TypeID
                )
     )
  )

    BEGIN
        ROLLBACK TRANSACTION
    END
END
```

Comment: But is it "better" than two separate triggers? That's the main question.

Comment: Nope not really or maybe it is not sure :S I think there isnt any difference. It will reduce the number of triggers fired , you can consider this as a good point, In future if a change in logic is required only one trigger will need to be altered another good reason to combine it.

Comment: I'd say that the answer would be the philosophical "it depends".  If the two items have a lot in common and are minor, then by all means join them for the added performance.  But if they are very different or intricate, then rather separate them.  For the above, I would definitely join them